# Find four smooth $C^{\infty}$ real functions satisfying a certain property around the origin

Tags: functions, polynomials, smooth-functions, elementary-functions

In the book "A Singular Mathematical Promenade", there's a Theorem of Kontsevich:

It's impossible to find polynomials $P_1(x)$, $P_2(x)$, $P_3(x)$, $P_4(x)$ satisfying the following two conditions:

$1$. For small $x<0$:

$$P_1(x) < P_2(x) < P_3(x) < P_4(x)$$

$2$. For small $x>0$:
$$ P_2(x) < P_4(x) < P_1(x) < P_3(x)$$

However, the book goes on to say that if we relax the condition for $P_i$, allowing them to be just smooth $C^{\infty}$ functions, it is possible to find $P_1(x)$, $P_2(x)$, $P_3(x)$, $P_4(x)$  satisfying the above conditions.

I have tried a lot, but without success.

First I considered $P_1(x)$ to be the zero function so I could reduce the problem to just three functions.

I tried a wide array from exponentials, to trigonometrics, logarithms, but nothing works.

I suspect that "traditional" smooth functions, won't satisfy the property because around the origin it all boils down again to (Taylor) polynomials.

Can anyone here provide an explicit quartet of functions satisfying propeties $1$ and $2$? Can they be functions defined by a single branch? Or must we always define two branches?

Comment: Try letting each $$P_i(x)=\begin{cases}p_ie^{-1/x^2}&x>0\\n_ie^{-1/x^2}&x<0\\0 &x=0\end{cases}.$$
for pairs of real numbers $p_i,n_i.$ 

$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}, f(0)=0$ is a fairly famous function which is infinitely differentiable, and has derivative $0$ at $x=0$ for all degrees. So each $P_i$ is $C^{\infty}.$ The order of the $P_i(x)$ for $x>0$ is determined by the order of the $p_i.$ And the order of the $P_i(x)$ for $x<0$ is determined by the order of the $n_i.$

Comment: You’ll need something like this because if the $P_i$ are analytic near $0,$ (has a converging power series near $0,$) then we can determine their orders on either side of $0$ in terms of all the derivatives of the $P_i$ at $x=0.$ $f$ is famous because it is $C^{\infty},$ but the power series does not converge to $f$ in any interval containing $0.$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Just as I suspected, being analytic around 0 will reduce the problem again to the polynomials, thus rendering it impossible.